# Shouldn't coefficient of linear expansion decrease as the temperature rises?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

According to formula
$$\alpha=\frac{\Delta L}{L_0 \Delta T} \quad , $$

we can say that the $\alpha$ is inversely proportional to change in temperature, thus when temperature rises, the coefficient of linear expansion should decrease, why isn't it so according to you?

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format equations. You should check the derivation of this equation, I guess. In particular, note the assumptions made under which this equation is valid. That being said, note that $\Delta L$ obviously depends on $T$... Your question can be rephrased as: "Given $y(x)=\alpha\, x$, i.e. $\alpha=y/x$ - why does $\alpha$ decrease when increasing $x$?"- do you see the error in your line of thought?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of the linear approximation $\Delta L = \alpha L_0 \Delta T$?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/200704/)